# EXEC() in php, cec-client raspberry

Tags: php, path, exec, raspberry-pi

I would like lauched a command in php over my RPI.

The command is `echo 'standby 0' | cec-client -s`, it's work fine in ssh my Tv shutdown, but in php `echo shell_exec("......")` return  adapters autodetect FAILED ... But also mkdir doesn't work with sheel_exec, so i think it's probably PATH problem, but i don't know how to fix it. My PATH in ssh is /usr/local/bin....... and in php is /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin .

How i can fix it. Sorry for my english ...

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same and got a message saying "failed to open vchiq instance". I found a [question on Raspberry Pi StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19436/how-can-i-permanently-fix-dev-vchiq-permission-errors) suggesting to add the user to the "video" group. I did that with `usermod -a -G video www-data` and then restarted apache with `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`. Then I was able to use cec-client from PHP and apache.

Answer (score 0):

It is permissions problem. While running command via ssh you  executing it as user pi(probably), but via shell_exec  you execute command as user www-data which do not have necessary permissions. You can check this by running echo shell_exec("whoami"); 
You can easly fix this by adding line "www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" into your "/etc/sudoers" file and then run "echo shell_exec("sudo echo 'standby 0' | sudo cec-client -s");", hovewer this will add to the user www-data all of the sudo permissions and it is very unsecure, but it will work. If you want to do it more secure way you need to find which permissions cec-client required to run properly and then add them to user www-data.