# cec-client trough php returns nothing

Tags: php, linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, hdmi

I am trying turn on my TV via the web, i am trying to do this via Raspberry PI LibCec module.

when i run `echo shell_exec("sudo echo 'on 0' | cec-client -s");`
nothing is returned on the php page and my TV is NOT on.

When i run the same command `sudo echo 'on 0' | cec-client -s` (or without `sudo` ) in ssh connection the tv turns on, EVEN when i login as www-data on ssh.

When i run `echo shell_exec('whoami');` i do get `www-data` as result so whats going on?

The question has been asked before but there isnt any confirmation on the priviliges as answered here:
[EXEC() in php, cec-client raspberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920565/exec-in-php-cec-client-raspberry)

Answer (score 1):

YES!

It was a $PATH problem, as i ran `echo $PATH` on php i got a smaller list then i got on my ssh session.

So to solve it in my case i used full path towards cec-client
which was:
`/opt/xbmc-bcm/xbmc-bin/bin/cec-client`

as that was the only cec-client i could find...

Hope this helps others!

Would someone please help me by telling me how to make my php session `$path` include the path towards my `cec-client`
as i dont want to use the full dir all the time.